# Woocommerce: order posts by meta key

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, post-meta, get-posts

I have the following args array

```
{  
   "ordreby":"meta_value_num",
   "meta_key":"_price",
   "posts_per_page":10,
   "offset":0,
   "post_type":"product",
   "post_status":"publish",
   "order":"asc",
   "suppress_filters":false,

}
```

when i do

```
  $myposts = get_posts($args);
```

the order by **_price** (or other meta keys) is not working.

any  idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`"ordreby":"meta_value_num"`

for

```
"orderby":"meta_value_num"
```

a dyslexic error xD

Answer (score 1):

`meta_query` should be an array of arrays like:

```
...
'meta_query' => [
    [
        'key' => '...',
        'value' => '...',
    ],
],
...
```

Comment: is an array of arrays. The problem is in order by _price